# x86 4byte floats vs. 8byte doubles (vs. long long)?

Tags: c++, x86, floating-point, double

We have a measurement data processing application and currently all data is held as C++ `float` which means 32bit/4byte on our x86/Windows platform. (32bit Windows Application).

Since precision is becoming an issue, there have been discussions to move to another datatype. The options currently discussed are switching to `double` (8byte) or implementing a fixed decimal type on top of `__int64` (8byte).

The reason the fixed-decimal solution using `__int64` as underlying type is even discussed is that someone claimed that `double` performance is (still) significantly worse than processing `float`s and that we might see significant performance benefits using a native integer type to store our numbers. (Note that we *really* would be fine with fixed decimal precision, although the code would obviously become more complex.)

Obviously we need to benchmark in the end, but I would like to ask whether the statement that doubles are worse holds any truth looking at modern processors? I guess for large arrays doubles may mess up cache hits more that floats, but otherwise I really fail to see how they could differ in performance?

Comment: "[doubles] mess up cache hits more that floats, but otherwise I really fail to see how they could differ in performance?" ummm... isn't calculating more precise results at least a potentially more time consuming task too? I've never benchmarked this stuff though....  I'd be more suspicious re more sophisticated functions like logs or powers.

Comment: Why not write a simple stress test to compare arithmetic operations with an array of floats vs an array doubles and verify the result first-hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you do. Additions, subtractions and multiplies on `double` are just as fast as on `float` on current x86 and POWER architecture processors. Divisions, square roots and transcendental functions (exp, log, sin, cos, etc.) are usually notably slower with double arguments, since their runtime is dependent on the desired accuracy.

If you go fixed point, multiplies and divisions need to be implemented with long integer multiply / divide instructions which are usually slower than arithmetic on `double`s (since processors aren't optimized as much for it). Even more so if you're running in 32 bit mode where a long 64 bit multiply with 128 bit results needs to be synthesized from several 32-bit long multiplies!

Cache utilization is a red herring here. 64-bit integers and doubles are the same size - if you need more than 32 bits, you're gonna eat that penalty no matter what.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that we're gonna need 64bit anyway - at least the cache argument is out of the window now!

Answer (score 4):

Look it up. Both and Intel publish the instruction latencies for their CPUs in freely available PDF documents on their websites.

However, *for the most part*, performance won't be significantly different, or a couple of reasons:

- when using the x87 FPU instead of SSE, all floating point operations are calculated at 80 bits precision internally, and then rounded off, which means that the actual computation is equally expensive for all floating-point types. The only cost is really memory-related then (in terms of CPU cache and memory bandwidth usage, and that's only an issue in `float` vs `double`, but irrelevant if you're comparing to `int64`)
- with or without SSE, nearly all floating-point operations are pipelined. When using SSE, the `double` instructions *may* (I haven't looked this up) have a higher latency than their `float` equivalents, but the throughput is the same, so it should be possible to achieve similar performance with `doubles`.

It's also not a given that a fixed-point datatype would actually be faster either. It might, but the overhead of keeping this datatype consistent after some operations might outweigh the savings. Floating-point operations are fairly cheap on a modern CPU. They have a bit of latency, but as mentioned before, they're generally pipelined, potentially hiding this cost.

So my advice:

1. Write some quick tests. It shouldn't be that hard to write a program that performs a number of floating-point ops, and then measure how much slower the `double` version is relative to the `float` one.
2. Look it up in the manuals, and see for yourself if there's any significant performance difference between `float` and `double` computations

Answer (score 3):

I've trouble the understand the rationale "as double as slower than float we'll use 64 bits int".  Guessing performance has always been an black art needing much of experience, on today hardware it is even worse considering the number of factors to take into account.  Even measuring is difficult.  I know of several cases where micro-benchmarks lent to one solution but in context measurement showed that another was better.

First note that two of the factors which have been given to explain the claimed slower double performance than float are not pertinent here: bandwidth needed will the be same for double as for 64 bits int and SSE2 vectorization would give an advantage to double...

Then consider than using integer computation will increase the pressure on the integer registers and computation units when apparently the floating point one will stay still.  (I've already seen cases where doing integer computation in double was a win attributed to the added computation units available)

So I doubt that rolling your own fixed point arithmetic would be advantageous over using double (but I could be showed wrong by measures).

Answer (score 2):

Implementing 64 fixed points isn't really fun. Especially for more complex functions like `Sqrt` or logarithm. Integers will probably still a bit faster for simple operations like additions. And you'll need to deal with integer overflows. And you need to be careful when implementing rounding, else errors can easily accumulate.

We're implementing fixed points in a C# project because we need determinism which floatingpoint on .net doesn't guarantee. And it's relatively painful. Some formula contained `x^3` bang int overflow. Unless you have really compelling reasons not to, use float or double instead of fixedpoint.

SIMD instructions from SSE2 complicate the comparison further, since they allow operation on several floating point numbers(4 floats or 2 doubles) at the same time. I'd use double and try to take advantage of these instructions. So double will probably be significantly slower than floats, but comparing with ints is difficult and I'd prefer float/double over fixedpoint is most scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to measure instead of guess.  Yes, on many architectures, calculations on `double`s process twice the data as calculations on `float`s (and `long double`s are slower still).  However, as other answers, and comments on this answer, have pointed out, the x86 architecture doesn't follow the same rules as, say, ARM processors, SPARC processors, etc.  On x86 `float`s, `double`s and `long double`s are all converted to `long double`s for computation.  I should have known this, because the conversion causes x86 results to be more accurate than SPARC and Sun went through a lot of trouble to get the less accurate results for Java, [sparking some debate](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/reports/jgfnwg-01.html#floating-point) (note, that page is from 1998, things have since changed).

Additionally, calculations on `double`s are built in to the CPU where calculations on a fixed decimal datatype would be written in software and potentially slower.

You should be able to find a decent fixed sized decimal library and compare.

Comment: At least on x86, basic floating-point arithmetic (add/subtract/multiply) is always performed at >80-bit (`long double`) accuracy and then rounded to the currently specified precision. Most basic instructions take the same time on `float`, `double` and `long double` (note that most Windows compilers have `long double` == `double` - they'll never use 80-bit floats).

Comment: @Fabian Giesen, actually, if you enable SSE2, float calculations are no longer done with the x87 hardware.

Comment: They're no longer done with x87 *instructions*, but it's the same *hardware* that executes both SSE2 and x87 code, and the adders/multipliers still support full-width operations at no extra cost, even though the results don't get written back to registers.

Comment: It's not precisely the same hardware that's being used; SSE2 uses registers and x87 uses the FP stack. Sure, the adders could be shared. Doesn't make the x87 code equally fast: it needs a lot of stack shuffling to get the operands for each operation in place.

Comment: @Fabian: as far as I know, no. When you use SSE, the computations are performed at the "actual" data size. Floats at 32-bit and double at 64. The 80-bit internal precision is only for the x87 FPU (unless you've got some evidence to the contrary?)

Comment: @MSalters The x87 stack has a fixed size (8 entries), which is effectively just registers. The stack-shuffling is resolved with register renaming and has been effectively free since the original Pentium. @jalf Yes, SSE doesn't have higher precision intermediary results, but it still *uses the same FP ALU*. If that ALU can do 80-bit adds with the same 3-cycle latency you get for 32-bit adds (which is how it is right now), it seems very unlikely that 64-bit adds which again use the same HW are slower :)

Comment: @Fabian Giesen: the instructions may be free to execute, in the sense that they're eliminated at the instruction execution stage. They still have to reside in L1 cache and be decoded. (They might be eliminated in the trace cache, I can't say - depends on the register renaming I assume.)

Comment: @MSalters Yep, x87 needs more instructions, but they're smaller (no extra prefix bytes). Code size is usually very similar between x87/SSE. No x86 family processor since P4 has used a trace cache, but P4 had `FXCH` executing with no latency whatsoever, so I guess it got eliminated. SSE is faster for typical code, but that has nothing to do with the stack or extra instructions executed and everything to do with having 1. Direct int->float, float->int conversion from/to integer GPRs 2. A float->int conversion that always truncates (important for C code!) 3. FP compares that directly set EFLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

With various SIMD instruction sets you can perform 4 single precision floating point operations at the same cost as one, essentially you pack 4 floats into a single 128 bit register. When switching to doubles you can only pack 2 doubles into these registers and hence you can only do two operations at the same time.

Comment: As long as your code isn't auto-vectorized (I've never seen that work on any loops that weren't completely trivial) or uses intrinsics, it either uses scalar SSE or x87 floating point operations. Both of them only pack one value into a register so the lower SIMD width doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

As many people have said, a 64bit int is probably not worth it if double is an option. At least when SSE is available. This might be different on micro controllers of various kinds but I guess that is not your application. If you need additional precision in long sums of floats, you should keep in mind that [this operation is sometimes problematic](http://baumdevblog.blogspot.com/2010/11/fast-kahan-summation-implementation-in.html) with floats and doubles and would be more exact on integers.